# Replace NAs in column based on values in other column r dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df :

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8),
                 var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'h'),
                 var2 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                 var3 = c(21, 50, 40, NA, 29, 45, NA, NA, NA, 46))
```

I would like to replace NAs in var3 based on the values in ID, with something like the following:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(var3 = case_when(var3 == NA  & ID == 3 ~ 5,
                        var3 == NA  & ID == 5 ~ 5,
                        var3 == NA  & ID == 7 ~ 5,
                        TRUE ~ var3
  ))
```

But for some reason it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(var3 = case_when(is.na(var3)==TRUE  & ID == 3 ~ 5,
                          is.na(var3)==TRUE  & ID == 5 ~ 5,
                          is.na(var3)==TRUE  & ID == 7 ~ 5,
                          TRUE ~ var3
  ))
```

Comment: I think this is what you want? replacing NA's with 5?

Comment: Yes but the new value varies for my real dataset. This does the trick, thanks. Can I ask what the ==T is for?

Comment: Just a boolean, "T" stand for `TRUE` I'll update my post and add the whole word. You can use "T" or "TRUE" to specify true and "F" or "FALSE" to specify false

Comment: `is.na()` tests for presence of NA and returns true or false. R handles NA's in seemingly strange ways sometimes and trying to find NA's the way you did often throws an error or a warning suggesting the use of `is.na()` instead.

Comment: Is it always necessary? It seems to work with and without the ==T/==TRUE

Comment: I guess not in the case when you are searching for true (it must default to that). But if you wanted to search for places where `is.na(var3)==F` you would need to specify it. I like to explicitly state things like that even if the default behavior works for ease of understanding later on.

Comment: Someone else may have a deeper understanding of it, and you can certainly dig around the help file, but I've not come across an example where explicitly including the `==T` has caused a problem, but suspect there could be cases where not including it would be problematic.